# Ordering of git child maven projects in Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have a git projects having child projects.

Sample representation:

```
parent 

  core
   -src
   -pom.xml

  projA
   -src
   -pom.xml

  projB

    projB1 
     -src
     -pom.xml

    projB2
     -src
     -pom.xml

  projC
   -src
   -pom.xml

pom.xml (parent pom)
```

`projA`, `projB1`, `projB2`and `projC` are independent projects which uses internally `core` project. **In real, there are around 8-10 independent projects.**

I am using Jenkins for CI. I am using git plugin to fetch project details and maven plugin to build the project and run test cases.

I am simply using `clean install` goal.

Currently, I created a single job. some of the projects took more time (1-2 hours) to run all the test cases. Using this approach, the order of execution of projects is **random**.

---

- Is there any better way to handle this in a better way and control order of build execution so that I build fragile modules first & stable ones later?
- After building `core` module I want to build other modules in parallel (*2 or 3 at a time*) to fast build process. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the maven build on the parent project is not exactly random. As per the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html):

> **The Reactor**
>
> The mechanism in Maven that handles multi-module projects is referred
>   to as the reactor. This part of the Maven core does the following:
>
> - Collects all the available modules to build
> - Sorts the projects into the correct build order
> - Builds the selected projects in order
>
> **Reactor Sorting**
>
> Because modules within a multi-module build can depend on each other,
>   it is important that The reactor sorts all the projects in a way that
>   guarantees any project is built before it is required.
>
> The following relationships are honoured when sorting projects:
>
> 1. a project dependency on another module in the build
> 2. a plugin declaration where the plugin is another modules in the build
> 3. a plugin dependency on another module in the build
> 4. a build extension declaration on another module in the build
> 5. the order declared in the `<modules>` element (if no other rule applies)
>
> Note that only "instantiated" references are used -
>   dependencyManagement and pluginManagement elements will not cause a
>   change to the reactor sort order

Given that it takes that long to build all of it, I suspect that you may be running some integration tests as well. Thus, I'd try to isolate them and run everything during a nightly build, while running the (hopefully & desirably) fast unit test in a continuous integration build after each commit.

Regarding the setup for parallelism, there are a few options which have one thing in common: creating a job for each of the modules. To enumerate a few (you can read a nice description for some of them [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/)):

- `build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built` trigger
- `build after other projects are built` trigger
- [Build-pipeline-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)
- [Parametrized-trigger-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)
- [pipelines](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology)

Personally I've used just the implicit [upstream-downstream](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology) support for maven jobs & the `snapshot dependency` trigger, meaning that Jenkins analyses the dependencies between the modules and triggers builds for the appropriate dependant jobs.